# How to know "y" property of an Item when it is created in a ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I use a `ListView` and **I need to fill my Window with the last `Item` that was inserted inside it.**
In this case, I set the `ListView` property: `contentY` with the `y` value of my`Item`

My problem is that when you insert a new Item, **I don't know how to know the `y` value of the Item because it is not yet set**.

This is what I try:

```
ScrollView {
    id: scroll
    ListView {
        model: DelegateModel {
            id: visualModel
            model: myModel //Model is set in the cpp
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: rectangleDelegate

                Component.onCompleted: {
                   rectangleDelegate.ListView.view.contentY = rectangleDelegate.y
                   console.log(rectangleDelegate.y ) //Not set yet (y = 0)
                }

                Button {
                    onClicked { 
                        rectangleDelegate.ListView.view.contentY = rectangleDelegate.y
                        console.log(rectangleDelegate.y ) //Now it is ok (y = rightValue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I proceed ?

Comment: Use `onYChanged` instead.

Comment: Remember, that not all Objects are necessary created, and the values might change, as QML only estimates the position based on the avereage size of the currently created objects.

Comment: `onYchanged` is fine. I do not update the size of my objects but this is an interessanting thing to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @derM, here is a simple example that works:

```
ScrollView {
    id: scroll
    ListView {
        model: DelegateModel {
            id: visualModel
            model: myModel //Model is set in the cpp
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: rectangleDelegate

                onYchanged: {
                   rectangleDelegate.ListView.view.contentY = rectangleDelegate.y
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```